# Making an array by giving two number from user and print the array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, printing, range, user-input

I want to give two number from user and make an array. Then print the array. How should I do this task in java?

This is my code. I give numbers 5 and 25. But it doesn't work properly.

My desired output: `[6,7,....,23,24]`

system output with inputs *min value: 5* and *max value: 25*

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication18 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("min value: ");
        int min = reader.nextInt();

        // Ask the user to input the minimum value
        System.out.print("max value: ");
        int max = reader.nextInt();
    
        for (int a = min; a < max; a++) {
            int [] userArray = new int[a]; 
            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(userArray));
        }
    }
}
```

My desired output for values 5 and 25: `[6,7,...,23,24]`

Comment: In general, there should be an explanation, not just an example, of what should be done. Don't count on an example without explanation being properly understood.

Answer (score 2):

A better and cleaner way to do this is by using Streams API

```
System.out.println(IntStream
                      .range(min + 1, max)
                      .boxed()
                      .collect(Collectors.toList())
                   );
```

**IntStream** :- A sequence of primitive int-valued elements supporting sequential and parallel aggregate operations. This is the int primitive specialization of Stream.

**range()** :- `static IntStream range(int startInclusive,   int endExclusive)`

**boxed()** :- returns a Stream consisting of the elements of this stream, each boxed to an Integer.

Comment: Thanks. Made the change.

Comment: You could skip the _boxing_, too.  `int[] a = IntStream.range(min + 1, max).toArray()`.

Comment: The ultimate goal is to print the numbers.

Comment: Oh, right.  With that, you can skip the _Collectors_ call, and just use _toList_ on your _boxed_ call.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are not creating one single array but one array in each iteration with the line `int [] userArray = new int[a];` inside the `for` loop. That explains your undesired system output, which shows several arrays…

You have to **create the array** with the correct size **outside** the loop and then just **fill it inside** calculating the correct indexes and values.

Here's an example method/function:

```
public static void printArray(int min, int max) {
    // create an array with the amount of numbers between from and to
    int[] array = new int[max - min - 1];
    // iterate from minimum to maximum (each exclusively)
    for (int i = min + 1; i < max; i++) {
        // and put the number at indexes starting by 0
        array[i - min - 1] = i;
    }
    // print the array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Calling it in a `main(…)` using your example values, like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printArray(5, 25);
}
```

would produce the following (desired) output:

```
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

Comment: Why 5 is in array? We want numbers within range. I mean numbers after min value and before max value. 6,....,24

Comment: I can not understand this code what job is doing?
array[i - min] = i;

Comment: @ZeynabMoghaddas, looks like a typo; start _i_ at _min + 1_.

Comment: @ZeynabMoghaddas Sorry, that was a mistake by me… I just corrected the algorithm and output! And the expression `array[i - min - 1] = i` means you put the value `i` at the index `i - min - 1` in the array.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... This is my code. I give numbers 5 and 25. But it doesn't work properly.
>
>
>
> My desired output: `[6,7,....,23,24]` ..."*

Declare *userArray* before the *loop*, and *print* after.

Additionally, the array should be initialized to a length of, *max − min − 1*.
Variable *a* should start at, *min + 1*.
And, utilize an additional variable, *i*, for *userArray* access.

```java
int [] userArray = new int[max - min - 1];
for (int i = 0, a=min + 1; a<max; i++, a++) {
    userArray[i] = a;
}
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(userArray));
```

Output

```
min value: 5
max value: 25
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
```

Here is the *Java* tutorial on *arrays*.
*[Arrays (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)*.